# how to use one state in two component / shere state

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Context = React.createContext();
export const ContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ open, setOpen }}>{children}</Context.Provider>
  );
};
```

componen1

```
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import { Context } from '../context/Context';
    
    export default function SideNav({ surahs }) {
      const { open, setOpen } = useContext(Context);
      return (
        <div className={`${open} bg-red`}></div>
    );
}
```

componen2

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context } from '../context/Context';

export default function Nav() {
  const { open, setOpen } = useContext(Context);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setOpen((o) => (o === false ? 'hidden' : 'block'));
  };
  return (
    <button onClick={clickHandler}></button>
  );
 }
```

how to trigger component 2, once the button on component 1 is clicked it will trigger component 2 and add or remove block and hidden classes

this confuses me

Comment: Create a state variable for selected item. Use this to add `item-active` class. On change of this variable, update filterItems. With react, you need to change your approach to be a data based approach instead of element based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need a state to monitor which category is currently active.

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState("All"); // possible values [All, Web, App, Design]
```

Then, you need to set and unset the `item-active` class depending on which category is active.

You can do the primitive way

```
className={`work__item ${category === "All" ? "item-active" : ""}`}
```

Or using a small utility library [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx)

```
clsx("work__item", { "item-active":  category === "All"})
```

Putting everything together:

```
import React, { useMemo, useState } from "react";
import "./portfolio.css";
import Menu from "./Menu";
import clsx from "clsx";

const Portfolio = () => {
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("All");
  // a computed variable "items" which update itself only when "category" is changed
  const items = useMemo(
    // array filter, get items when category matches or when category is selected to "All"
    () => Menu.filter(({ category: c }) => c === category || category === "All"),
    [category] // watch "category" state, update "items" when "category" changes
  );

  return (
    <div className="work__filters container">
      <span
        className={clsx("work__item", { "item-active": category === "All" })}
        onClick={() => setCategory("All")}
      >
        All
      </span>
      <span
        className={clsx("work__item", { "item-active": category === "Web" })}
        onClick={() => setCategory("Web")}
      >
        Web
      </span>
      <span
        className={clsx("work__item", { "item-active": category === "App" })}
        onClick={() => setCategory("App")}
      >
        App
      </span>
      <span
        className={clsx("work__item", { "item-active": category === "Design" })}
        onClick={() => setCategory("Design")}
      >
        Design
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};
```